# before_add callback, 'Called id for nil object' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the classic `'Called id for nil...` error but I'm struggling to see why my object is nil.

It errors in the `validate_assignee` method when trying to grab the id of the :agent the task belongs to.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_one :agent, through: :users
has_and_belongs_to_many :assignees,
                      class_name: "User",
                      before_add: :validate_assignee
private
  def validate_assignee(assignee)
    #need to check that the :assignee belongs to the same :agent as the :user
    #grab agent_id from self
    current_agent_id = self.agent.id 
    #fails here on create of a Task through the @user.tasks.build association
    ...
  end
end
```

From the console I get the expected behaviour when I build a task via

```
> task = @user.tasks.build ...
> task.agent.id
=> 1
```

My create action in the TasksController:

```
def create
  @task = current_user.tasks.build(params[:task])
  ...
end
```

Is there something strange about using self in this context when the object hasn't yet been saved?  Is there a better way of doing this?  I'm at the stage where I need another pair of eyes on this as I'm going round in circles.  Thanks.

**Update:** 
In order to eliminate `current_user` from the process I have changed the task.build in the create action to explicitly build a task through the User association, and with a User that I know belongs to an agent.

```
@task = User.find(1).tasks.build(params[:task])
```

When I then output a representation of the object inside the `validate_assignee` method like this `puts self.to_yaml` I see that the Task doesn't have a `user_id` set.

**So in summary** - I'm building a new Task object through the User association in my create action but in the Task model inside the method called by the before_add association callback it has lost the association with the User.

Comment: Is your `current_user` same as `@user`(what you tested in console). I think your `current_user` doesn't have `agent`.

Comment: It is the currently authenticated user, which belongs_to the :agent

Comment: Whats the user `id` of your authenticated user which creating error? Once you get the user id. Then try `User.find(id).agent` I think it is `nil`.

Comment: Quick question: Do you have agent for every user?

Comment: Yes, every user is created via the agent association, never by calling User.create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It appears** that until the record is saved, you cannot access the associated properties of the object. That's what [this chap says](http://mattberther.com/2012/09/09/validating-habtm-relationships-with-rails-3x).  So instead, I've added an `after_save` callback to my Task model to call my validation method in which everything works as expected.

When outputting the task via `self.to_yaml` in the validation method I see the `user_id` value as expected.  It's just a shame that I have to actually save the record and the habtm association before I can validate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have `agent` for your `current_user`. When you don't have `agent` for `user`:

```
   current_user.agent  #=> nil
```

So, when call `id` on `nil` it throws error.

```
   current_user.agent.id #=> Throws error
```

If you don't have `agent` for every `user` you can use `try` to avoid error:

```
   current_agent_id = self.agent.try(:id)
```

Comment: Sadly this isn't it - every user has an agent and every new user is created via the Agent association, never through User.create.  I have double checked that this is the case.

Comment: Please see latest update - the Task is losing the User association somewhere between the create action in the controller and when the model is saved.