# Issue with collection `build` method record instantiation in Rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem with the Rails `collection.build(attrs)` method, specifically with how the framework instantiates a new record. For example, here is a much simplified view of my models:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :descriptions, before_add: :id_test
  validates :account, presence: true
  def id_test
    puts self.account_id
  end
end
```

When I do something like:

```
current_account.documents.build(:descriptions => [desc])
```

then `id_test` prints nothing. That is, the `account_id` is not set in the `before_add` callback (and yes, I've tried the `after_add` callback as well; `account_id` is not set in that case either).

If I do:

```
d = current_account.documents.build
d.assign_attributes(:descriptions => [desc])
```

Then everything works as expected. However, I would prefer a better alternative, since this would be a pain to implement in the controllers...

Is there a way to get Rails to add the foreign_key first, or is there some better way to set this up? I haven't gone back to check for sure, but this seems different than the way Rails 3 evaluated `collection.build` statements.

**EDIT**

Looking through the Rails code a bit, I see I can do:

```
current_account.documents.build do |record|
  record.assign_attributes(:descriptions => [desc])
end
```

and everything works as expected. Although a bit more verbose, I guess this is technically more accurate anyway.

Comment: Hoping to help, but I was under the impression that associative `build` method would populate the `foreign_key` anyway

Comment: The accepted answer in this question might shed some light onto the behavior you are seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590013/before-add-callback-called-id-for-nil-object-error

Comment: @enragedcamel, thanks for the link. That question does seem to describe the same issue, though I don't think saved status is really the problem in either case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using

```
Document.build(:account_id => current_account.id, :descriptions => [desc])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. That does work as expected, but I've updated my question with a workaround that I think I prefer over this one.